# How to populate null values with above row data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a sample data

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        ID INT,
        Mon VARCHAR(10),
        Dt DateTime 
)

INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Mon,Dt) SELECT 1, 'Jan','2016-12-23 21:08:22.280'
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Mon,Dt) SELECT 2, 'Feb',NULL
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Mon,Dt) SELECT 3, 'Mar',NULL
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Mon,Dt) SELECT 4, 'Apr',NULL
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Mon,Dt) SELECT 5, 'May',NULL
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Mon,Dt) SELECT 6, 'Jun',NULL
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Mon,Dt) SELECT 7, 'Jul',NULL
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Mon,Dt) SELECT 8, 'Aug',NULL
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Mon,Dt) SELECT 9, 'Sep',NULL
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Mon,Dt) SELECT 10, 'Oct',NULL
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Mon,Dt) SELECT 11, 'Nov',NULL
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Mon,Dt) SELECT 12, 'Dec',NULL
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Mon,Dt) SELECT 1, 'Jan','2017-12-23 21:08:22.280'
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Mon,Dt) SELECT 2, 'Feb',NULL
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Mon,Dt) SELECT 3, 'Mar',NULL
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Mon,Dt) SELECT 4, 'Apr',NULL
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Mon,Dt) SELECT 5, 'May',NULL
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Mon,Dt) SELECT 6, 'Jun',NULL
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Mon,Dt) SELECT 7, 'Jul',NULL
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Mon,Dt) SELECT 8, 'Aug',NULL
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Mon,Dt) SELECT 9, 'Sep',NULL
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Mon,Dt) SELECT 10, 'Oct',NULL
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Mon,Dt) SELECT 11, 'Nov',NULL
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Mon,Dt) SELECT 12, 'Dec',NULL
```

Select * from @Table

Giving result as

```
ID  Mon Dt
1   Jan 2016-12-23 21:08:22.280
2   Feb NULL
3   Mar NULL
4   Apr NULL
5   May NULL
6   Jun NULL
7   Jul NULL
8   Aug NULL
9   Sep NULL
10  Oct NULL
11  Nov NULL
12  Dec NULL
1   Jan 2017-12-23 21:08:22.280
2   Feb NULL
3   Mar NULL
4   Apr NULL
5   May NULL
6   Jun NULL
7   Jul NULL
8   Aug NULL
9   Sep NULL
10  Oct NULL
11  Nov NULL
12  Dec NULL
```

How can I get like this

```
 id mon dt
1   Jan 2016-01-23 21:08:22.280
2   Feb 2016-02-23 21:08:22.280
3   Mar 2016-03-23 21:08:22.280
4   Apr 2016-04-23 21:08:22.280
5   May 2016-05-23 21:08:22.280
6   Jun 2016-06-23 21:08:22.280
7   Jul 2016-07-23 21:08:22.280
8   Aug 2016-08-23 21:08:22.280
9   Sep 2016-09-23 21:08:22.280
10  Oct 2016-10-23 21:08:22.280
11  Nov 2016-11-23 21:08:22.280
12  Dec 2016-12-23 21:08:22.280
1   Jan 2017-01-23 21:08:22.280
2   Feb 2017-02-23 21:08:22.280
3   Mar 2017-03-23 21:08:22.280
4   Apr 2017-04-23 21:08:22.280
5   May 2017-05-23 21:08:22.280
6   Jun 2017-06-23 21:08:22.280
7   Jul 2017-07-23 21:08:22.280
8   Aug 2017-08-23 21:08:22.280
9   Sep 2017-09-23 21:08:22.280
10  Oct 2017-10-23 21:08:22.280
11  Nov 2017-11-23 21:08:22.280
12  Dec 2017-12-23 21:08:22.280
```

Suggest me

Comment: Note that you can use the more succint (and faster!) `INSERT INTO ( ... ) VALUES ( 1 ), ( 2 ), ( 3 ), ...` syntax instead of `INSERT SELECT INSERT SELECT`.

Comment: Which version of sql server you are using ?

Comment: sql server2012 @Prdp

Comment: why isn't id unique?

Comment: it is just sample data we should moistly concentrate on Date column @Hogan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT ID,
       Mon,
       Dateadd(mm, id - 1, Min(Dateadd(mm, -Month(dt) + 1, dt))OVER(partition BY rn)) dt
FROM   (SELECT Row_number()OVER(partition BY Mon ORDER BY id) rn,*
        FROM   @Table) a
ORDER  BY dt
```

**Result :**

```
╔════╦═════╦═════════════════════════╗
║ ID ║ Mon ║           dt            ║
╠════╬═════╬═════════════════════════╣
║  1 ║ Jan ║ 2016-01-23 21:08:22.280 ║
║  2 ║ Feb ║ 2016-02-23 21:08:22.280 ║
║  3 ║ Mar ║ 2016-03-23 21:08:22.280 ║
║  4 ║ Apr ║ 2016-04-23 21:08:22.280 ║
║  5 ║ May ║ 2016-05-23 21:08:22.280 ║
║  6 ║ Jun ║ 2016-06-23 21:08:22.280 ║
║  7 ║ Jul ║ 2016-07-23 21:08:22.280 ║
║  8 ║ Aug ║ 2016-08-23 21:08:22.280 ║
║  9 ║ Sep ║ 2016-09-23 21:08:22.280 ║
║ 10 ║ Oct ║ 2016-10-23 21:08:22.280 ║
║ 11 ║ Nov ║ 2016-11-23 21:08:22.280 ║
║ 12 ║ Dec ║ 2016-12-23 21:08:22.280 ║
║  1 ║ Jan ║ 2017-01-23 21:08:22.280 ║
║  2 ║ Feb ║ 2017-02-23 21:08:22.280 ║
║  3 ║ Mar ║ 2017-03-23 21:08:22.280 ║
║  4 ║ Apr ║ 2017-04-23 21:08:22.280 ║
║  5 ║ May ║ 2017-05-23 21:08:22.280 ║
║  6 ║ Jun ║ 2017-06-23 21:08:22.280 ║
║  7 ║ Jul ║ 2017-07-23 21:08:22.280 ║
║  8 ║ Aug ║ 2017-08-23 21:08:22.280 ║
║  9 ║ Sep ║ 2017-09-23 21:08:22.280 ║
║ 10 ║ Oct ║ 2017-10-23 21:08:22.280 ║
║ 11 ║ Nov ║ 2017-11-23 21:08:22.280 ║
║ 12 ║ Dec ║ 2017-12-23 21:08:22.280 ║
╚════╩═════╩═════════════════════════╝
```

Comment: @Prdp it is not giving 2017 result

Comment: exceptional @Prdp u nailed it

Comment: Using `row_number()` when the `id` column already has the value seems like overkill.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose this may be what you want:

```
select id, mon,
       coalesce(dt, min(dt) over ()) as dt
from @table;
```

This is assuming that you want to do is populate the `NULL` values with the minimum date/time in the column.

EDIT:

The revised version increments the month:

```
select id, mon,
       coalesce(dt, dateadd(month, id - 1, min(dt) over ())) as dt
from @table;
```

Comment: I have modified the question can you please check that

Comment: Eagle eyes man.. Didn't see that `2017-01-23 21:08:22.280` in expected result

Comment: Sorry I will edit the question @Prdp from 2017 it is incremental of 2017

Comment: `ISNULL` is better because it won't execute the `dateadd` part like `COALESCE`, right?

Comment: @Gordon can you please check with the result it is not populating according to date except  2016 it is full populating 2017 only

Comment: Isn't lag better if you want to add one month to the prior date?

Comment: @Hogan it is not about adding month if some date added it should populate for remaining months in incremental

Comment: @mohan111 -- so you want it to populate remaining months based on prior date?  That would be the LAG function.

Comment: can you please show me correct code to implement in my code @Hogan

Comment: @mohan111 there is no way to differentiate your table rows except those with the Dt value. You should have a year column or at least a different ID

Comment: @mohan111 -- I wrote an example using lag.

Answer (score 1):

assuming id is unique lag would work like this:

```
select id, mon,
       coalesce(dt, dateadd(month, 1, LAG(dt) over (order by id asc))) as dt
from @table;
```

since id is not unique in your example lag can't work (which I didn't notice when I made my original comment)  However, I suspect that id not being unique is just lazyness why making the example.

Answer (score 0):

you mean:

```
declare @table table (id int, mon varchar(3), Dt datetime)
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Mon,Dt) SELECT 1, 'Jan','2016-12-23 21:08:22.280'
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Mon,Dt) SELECT 2, 'Feb','2016-2-23 21:08:22.280'
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Mon,Dt) SELECT 3, 'Mar','2016-3-23 21:08:22.280'
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Mon,Dt) SELECT 4, 'Apr','2016-4-23 21:08:22.280'
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Mon,Dt) SELECT 5, 'May','2016-5-23 21:08:22.280'
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Mon,Dt) SELECT 6, 'Jun','2016-6-23 21:08:22.280'
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Mon,Dt) SELECT 7, 'Jul','2016-7-23 21:08:22.280'
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Mon,Dt) SELECT 8, 'Aug','2016-8-23 21:08:22.280'
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Mon,Dt) SELECT 9, 'Sep','2016-9-23 21:08:22.280'
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Mon,Dt) SELECT 10, 'Oct','2016-10-23 21:08:22.280'
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Mon,Dt) SELECT 11, 'Nov','2016-11-23 21:08:22.280'
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Mon,Dt) SELECT 12, 'Dec','2016-12-23 21:08:22.280'
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Mon,Dt) SELECT 1, 'Jan','2017-1-23 21:08:22.280'
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Mon,Dt) SELECT 2, 'Feb','2016-2-23 21:08:22.280'
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Mon,Dt) SELECT 3, 'Mar','2016-3-23 21:08:22.280'
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Mon,Dt) SELECT 4, 'Apr','2016-4-23 21:08:22.280'
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Mon,Dt) SELECT 5, 'May','2016-5-23 21:08:22.280'
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Mon,Dt) SELECT 6, 'Jun','2016-6-23 21:08:22.280'
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Mon,Dt) SELECT 7, 'Jul','2016-7-23 21:08:22.280'
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Mon,Dt) SELECT 8, 'Aug','2016-8-23 21:08:22.280'
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Mon,Dt) SELECT 9, 'Sep','2016-9-23 21:08:22.280'
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Mon,Dt) SELECT 10, 'Oct','2016-10-23 21:08:22.280'
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Mon,Dt) SELECT 11, 'Nov','2016-11-23 21:08:22.280'
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Mon,Dt) SELECT 12, 'Dec','2016-12-23 21:08:22.280'
Select * from @table
--<grin />
```

or actually,

```
 Select id, mon, 
    Dateadd(month, mon-1, '23Jan2016 21:08:22.280')
 from @table
```

Comment: @mohan111 never said it did, only that it was glorious. Even the insert statements are incorrect.

Comment: It was just a jest, (incomplete code).  I added the declare and Select to make it work anyway.